# multiple controller class files in action directory

Tags: magento2, php, controllers

I have module named Spaarg_Api.
and I have controller 
Controller/Customers/Index.php
and it is working fine, but when I try to create another file in Customer directory like Controller/Customers/List.php it gives 404.

Here is my **route.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="api" frontName="api">
            <module name="Spaarg_Api" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Here is my controllers

**Customers/Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Spaargcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Spaarg\Api\Controller\Customers;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool
     */
    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Flush cache storage
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
        $storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $baseUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl();

        $token = $this->getRequest()->getPost('token');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        $password = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        $contact_number = $this->getRequest()->getPost('contact_number');

        $addresses = array();
        $addresses['id'] = '0';
        $addresses['customer_id'] = '0';
        $addresses['region']['region_code'] = 'CA';
        $addresses['region']['region'] = 'California';
        $addresses['region']['region_id'] = '12';
        $addresses['region']['extension_attributes'] = '';
        $addresses['region_id'] = '12';
        $addresses['country_id'] = 'US';
        $addresses['street'][] = 'Zoe Ave';
        $addresses['company'] = 'None';
        $addresses['fax'] = 'None';
        $addresses['postcode'] = '90001';
        $addresses['city'] = 'Los Angeles';
        $addresses['firstname'] = 'None';
        $addresses['lastname'] = 'None';
        $addresses['middlename'] = 'None';
        $addresses['prefix'] = 'None';
        $addresses['suffix'] = 'None';
        $addresses['vat_id'] = 'None';
        $addresses['default_shipping'] = true;
        $addresses['default_billing'] = true;
        $addresses['extension_attributes'] = '';
        $addresses['telephone'] = $contact_number;

        $postArray = array();
        $postArray['customer']['id'] = '0';
        $postArray['customer']['group_id'] = '0';
        $postArray['customer']['default_billing'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['default_shipping'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['confirmation'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $postArray['customer']['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $postArray['customer']['created_in'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $postArray['customer']['dob'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $postArray['customer']['email'] = $email;
        $postArray['customer']['firstname'] = 'eMenu';
        $postArray['customer']['lastname'] = 'Customer';
        $postArray['customer']['middlename'] = '';
        $postArray['customer']['prefix'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['suffix'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['gender'] = '1';
        $postArray['customer']['store_id'] = '1';
        $postArray['customer']['taxvat'] = 'None';
        $postArray['customer']['website_id'] = '1';
        $postArray['customer']['addresses'][] = $addresses;
        $postArray['customer']['disable_auto_group_change'] = '0';
        $postArray['customer']['extension_attributes']['is_subscribed'] = true;
        $postArray['password'] = $password;
        $postArray['redirectUrl'] = '0';

        $ch = curl_init($baseUrl."rest/V1/customers");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postArray));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . $token));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = (array)json_decode($result,TRUE);
        $resultArray = array();
        if(!empty($result['id'])){

            $resultArray['customer']['id'] = $result['id'];
            $resultArray['customer']['email'] = $result['email'];
            $resultArray['customer']['contact_number'] = $result['addresses'][0]['telephone'];
            $resultArray['error'] = '200';
            $resultArray['message'] = 'You are successfully registered.';
        }
        else{
            $resultArray['error'] = '400';
            $resultArray['message'] = !empty($result['message'])?$result['message']:'Bad request.';
        }
        echo json_encode($resultArray); 
    }

    public function details()
    {
        echo "Hello there...!";
    }


}
```

**Customers/List.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Spaargcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Spaarg\Api\Controller\Customers;

class List extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hiii There, you calling me...?";exit;
    }

}
```

It will be great if someone can help.

Comment: Which Url you call for the second controller?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am calling [store_url]/api/customers/index it is working perfect, but [store_url]/api/customers/list is giving 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your file `ListAction.php` and your class `ListAction`.
It does not work with `List` because it is a reserved php word.
For all (declared) reserved php words, M2 appends `Action` to the name and then looks for the file. For the same reason all the `new` actions map to the file `NewAction.php`.
Here is an example of the [cms page new action controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/NewAction.php).
The file name is `/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/NewAction.php` but the url is `admin/cms/page/new`.
You can find a list of all reserved words that will get `Action` at the end of the file name in [`lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php#L30).
And in the same file in the method [`get`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php#L97) you will see `action` being appended to the file name

Comment: What is **a reserved php word**? You can explain more?

Comment: Thanks man ! worked for me, it was a great help. I think it's magento structure that controller other then default must be followed by Action

Comment: I edited my answer. But here is some context outside Magento for php reserved words  http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/reserved.htm

Comment: Great info @Marius